# Show close button when mouse hover on a word

Tags: css

I want to show the close image when the cursor hovers on the word.
The close image should be appearing on the top-left to the selected word.
However, it only show me one close button for all words.

[image: inline]

My objective is to have a close button like the word 'apps' in red does.

[image: inline]

```css
  span.mydict_highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}

span.birch_close_btn {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.6);
  left: -8px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: opacity 275ms, transform 275ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275), background 175ms;
  float: right;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.2;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat border-box;
```

```html
<span class="mydict_highlighted">
        building
        <span class="birch_close_btn"> </span>
</span>
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i was able to find a close solution

```
too many words around a closed
<span class="mydict_highlighted">building</span>
<span class="birch_close_btn"> but the</span> close button is <span class="mydict_highlighted">hard</span> to find 



// css rule you are looking for
     span.mydict_highlighted:hover:after {
       background: #abf;
       content: 'x';
       vertical-align: top;
       font-size: 0.7em;
     }
```

please refer to the link https://jsfiddle.net/0yd7L02x/

i was using chrome 56